# How to setup Gosu CodeNarc

Tags: gosu, codenarc

[image: codenarc report]

I have codenarc set up in my local windows machine with the following configuration. JDK 1.6 and Ant 1.7.1 integrated with claim center 7 version and also codenarc report has been successfully generated.

Now the question is there any way to add the user name who is modified and when a file has changed along with commit id information in codenarc HTML report file.

Please advice me and show if any sample file to accomplish this case study.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do that would be write a XSLT that would do the heavy lifting. The question would be, if the data you ask for to include is already available in the context (I guess the commit author and id are defined per line).

[Source](http://codenarc.sourceforge.net/codenarc-HtmlReportWriter.html)

[XSLT instructions](https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/01/groovy-goodness-create-codenarc-reports.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20mrhaki%20(Messages%20from%20mrhaki))

[Example XSLT](https://github.com/mrhaki/CodeNarc/tree/master/styles/styles)